# Slack message from Ansible is being sent as plaint text json

Tags: ansible, slack, slack-api

I'm using Ansible to send a message to Slack using the [ansible guidelines](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slack_module.html), but the message isn't formatting. For example, If I have

```
- name: "Slack test"
    slack:
      token: "abc123"
      channel: "some_channel"
      color: good
      msg: '{"text": "This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}'
```

in my Ansible task, then it will post the unformatted json `{"text": "This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."}` to the Slack channel. How can I have the JSON messages be formatted like in [Slack's message formatting guide](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not using the correct syntax for Ansible.

According to the documentation you linked the `msg` property should contain the text of the message directly, not a JSON structure with additional properties.

So this should be a corrected example:

```
- name: "Slack test"
    slack:
      token: "abc123"
      channel: "some_channel"
      color: good
      msg: "This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one."
```

To add formatting to your text you should be able use to Slack markup in the msg property. Example for bold:

```
- name: "Slack test"
        slack:
          token: "abc123"
          channel: "some_channel"
          color: good
          msg: "This is a *bold line* of text.\nAnd this is another one."
```